# Numeric data not transferred correctly with MVVM from server to client

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

in my asp.net mvc4 app I am using MVVM and ajax (with json datatype) to transfer a numeric value (in German numeric decimal separator: example 17,3) from a view (clientside) to the server. I am checking the result by looking at the entry in the corresponding sql database table field. The numeric value gets stored correctly (17,3). So far so good.
When I retrieve the value into the view again it is displayed with an English decimal separator (17.3). Saving this entry to the server results in a NULL entry in the sql database table.
When I enter a value of 17.3 manually into the view and save the entry to the server this also results in a NULL entry in the sql database table.

In the model and the viewmodel the property of the numeric entry is defined as double. In the view I am using  @Html.TextBoxFor(....)

Any suggestion what is causing this and how to fix this issue?

Thanks and regards, Manu

Comment: It sounds like you have a mismatch between the culture of the database and the culture of the UI.

Comment: In web.config. I have:  <globalization uiCulture="de" culture="de-AT"></globalization> . I thought that should do it.

Comment: @Manu I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

All the values in the DAL/transport layer should use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` for transmission and storage of data.

When you show the values, then bring in the appropriate `CultureInfo` to convert to and from a culture-specific rendering of the data.

Comment: Where and how would I accomplish that my numeric property (lets call it 'NumAmount') is of the type InvariantCulture? In the model I have defined it as double? In the modelView it is also a double. So I assume it must be somewhere when the ajax call is posted or when the controller fetches data from the server, right? But I have no clue how to make that 'the DAL/transport layer uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ...'.

Comment: In the DAL/transport layer, it's only typically an issue if you are doing a lot of string conversion of numbers/dates. The area for you to look at would be the conversion from front-end to model i.e. pass the appropriate `CultureInfo` into `Html.TextBoxFor`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to format the output from the database to the German culture. A sample:

```
var yourValue = 20.3;

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

var formattedValue = yourValue.ToString("F1", cultureInfo);

//formattedValue => 20,3;
```

**EDIT 1:**

Depending on your edit of the question I propose the following:

You can use

```
@{var formated = String.Format("{0:0.0}", yourValue);}
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => yourValue, formated, new { id = "yourId"})
```

Comment: Do I add the  var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de-DE"); into the script section of the page?

Comment: @Manu You could also try `Html.TextBox("abc", yourValue.ToString("F1", new CultureInfo("de-DE")));`. If my answer is useful, please upvote

Comment: Not completely yet. I want to keep working with Html.TextBoxFor(...) which does not allow to use a string when the model property is defined as double.

Comment: @ rbr94: I am pretty new with html5 ... don't kow where to put @{var formated = String.Format("{0:0.0}", yourValue);} into the view (razor) to make it available for the @Html.TextBoxFor(...). Placing it one line before the TextBoxFor does not work -> messes up the view in runtime.